# Is there a way to parse custom function in jooq?

Tags: java, sql, parsing, jooq

I want to parse my function on one dialect and render it afterwards to another dialect.

For instance, I have string like that in one dialect:

```
"(1 + my_function(myTable.id*2))/2"
```

And I want to parse and render it to another dialect like that:

```
"(1 + my_other_dialect_function(myTable.id*2))/2"
```

I've created `CustomField` inheritor, that will be rendered properly using [this example](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/):

```
class MyFunctionCustomFiled extends CustomField<Integer>
```

But I can't figure out the right way to insert it into expression.

Can I do that on parsing step? Or on render step using VisitListener like below?

```
public class CustomFunctionsFisitListener2 extends DefaultVisitListener {
  public void visitStart(VisitContext context){
    if(context.queryPart().isTheFunctionINeed()){
      Field<?> argument = context.queryPart().retrieveArgumentExpression();
      context.queryPart(MyFunctionCustomFiled(argument));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it similar to example given in "*An example for implementing vendor-specific functions*" section on the page you linked? Do I understand correctly that you have some specific function in dialect X, but want to use it somehow with dialect Y?

Comment: Yea, but in a more complex way. I don't create those jooq fields straight. I'm using [jooq sql parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-api/) for that. 

I have sql string with the function in dialect X. I want to parse this string and later render it into dialect Y. The problem is that the Parser creates org.jooq.impl.Function implementation of my function by default. I want to replace it with MyFunctionCustomFiled implementation so it renders properly. I just don't know how to do this not on a parsing step nor on the rendering step.

Comment: Curious: Are you using the parser mainly for such SQL transformation tasks, or for other use-cases as well?

Answer (score 1):

As of jOOQ version 3.12 (and the upcoming 3.13), you cannot access the jOOQ expression tree in a way for your `VisitListener` to *guarantee* that each call to the input function can be replaced by a call to the output function.

[There's a larger project on our roadmap](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/projects/2) to re-design the currently internal object model to make it public API, mainly for the precise purpose you're trying to use jOOQ for: As a parser that allows for transforming SQL expression trees. It's a lot of work, as we'll have to consolidate the various internal representations of what is really the same thing: e.g. a user defined function. As you've noticed in your comments, this is currently a `org.jooq.impl.Function`, but right now, there is no *guarantee* for a function to be represented by that type.

One thing you could already do today is use schemas to qualify your functions, and use the out of the box runtime schema mapping feature: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-render-mapping

The most pragmatic solution to your specific problem right now might be to regex-replace your function name prior to passing it to the parser, as I'm assuming the name should be sufficiently unique in your system.